# Retrieving image link after upload fails

Tags: android, image

I am trying to create a image upload module Using Imgur API 
I have just got Client ID and Client Secret after registration. When it comes to the implementation and testing, it fails and gives the following response in the logcat

The Logcat response

```
             {"data":{"error":"We're really sorry, but
         anonymous uploading in your country has 
been disabled. Please <a href=\"\/register\">register
         for an account<\/a> and try uploading again.","request":"\/3\/upload.json","method":"POST"}
    ,"success":false,"status":400}
```

The below is my code

```
public String uploadToImgur(File uploadFile) {
        DefaultHttpClient defaulthttpclient;
        HttpPost httppost;
        MultipartEntity multipartentity;
        String path = uploadFile.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        String s;
        defaulthttpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String targetURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json";
        String apikey = "client_secret";
        httppost = new HttpPost(targetURL);

        httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID {client)_id}");
        multipartentity = new MultipartEntity();
        s = path.substring(1 + path.lastIndexOf("."));
        if (s.lastIndexOf("jpg") >= 0)
        {
            s = "jpeg";
        }
        try
        {
            multipartentity.addPart("image", new FileBody(new File(path), (new StringBuilder("image/")).append(s).toString()));
            multipartentity.addPart("key", new StringBody(apikey));
            httppost.setEntity(multipartentity);
            String s1 = EntityUtils.toString(defaulthttpclient.execute(httppost).getEntity());
            Log.d("outpur" , s1);
            if (s1.lastIndexOf("<original>") >= 0 && s1.indexOf("</original>") >= 0)
            {
                return (new StringBuilder("[img]")).append(s1.substring(10 + s1.lastIndexOf("<original>"), s1.indexOf("</original>"))).append("[/img]").toString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return "ERRor";
        }
        return "Error";
    }
```

Would you please tell me what is the better way to enhance the upload module ?

Answer (score 0):

Registration and sending client id is not good enough for non anonymous uploads. The documentation tells you to use oAuth and get a token that needs to be passed for such requests.

**Authentication
The API requires each client to use OAuth 2 authentication. This means you'll have to register your application, and generate an access_code if you'd like to log in as a user.
For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests. This also works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API.
Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID
For accessing a user's account, please visit the OAuth2 section of the docs**

Comment: I don;t understand ...that is I have to get what code in order to use the API ?

Comment: Please check this document https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 which explains how imgur follows the standard oAuth protocol. At least from the document and the message you are receiving, it is clear you need to get an access token to make non anonymous uploads.